# Calculate Percentage of total within group

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have Crystal Report group on year. Within the group I have a distinctcount on emplyee number so I know how many emplyees were terminated within a given year.I also have formulas that I summarize using sum for years of service like lees than 1 year or equal to one year and less than 3 years, etc. I also have a formula that adds 2 of the summary fields together so I can get a total of how many terminations occured with less tha 3 years of service. This all works as it should but when I try to add in a formuaa to get a percent of the total Terminations I get the wrong calculation and the same result displayes in every year despite having different numbers

All summaries are in groupfooter
Total Terminations for 2023 65
summary for < 1 year 34
Summary for >=1<3 years 17
formula to add the 2 summeries -

```
sum({@<1})+ sum({@>=1<3})
```

formula to get percent of (51/65)

```
local numbervar Total :=sum({@<3Years});
if Total <> 0 then
Total/distinctcount({Employee.Employee_Number})*100
```

I put that formula in groupfooter and get 77.71% when 51/65 = 78.46
The output of 78.46 displays on every year, when there should be a different percent represenative of that years numbers.

what should I be doing differently? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: for a report that groups on {Product_Type.Product Type Name} the sum of a {@value} formula for the current Product Type Name (specified as the 2nd argument) is:

```
Sum ({@value}, {Product_Type.Product Type Name})
```

Comment: Thank you. your example and explanation did the trick. Everything is calculating as it should

Answer (score 0):

Group aggregate expressions (e.g. Group sum) in Crystal must provide a second argument that specifies the group value.
Your expressions are missing the 2nd argument, and hence they return the global (report-level) aggregate instead of the group-level aggregate.

Comment: OK-can you give me an example of the second argument. I have searched through the site to see if this question has been asked already but can't seem to find an apples to apples comparison. I'm still searching and if I figure it out, prior to any reply, I will  update you